# The official 7-inch touch-screen LCD does not work

Tags: pi-4, boot-issues

I tried to run Lineage 16.0 on my Raspberry Pi 4 and this [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWjge.jpg) happened.

It worked just fine with Raspbian.

Comment: Are you sure your OS has a driver fot the screen?

Comment: Does it work if you boot RaspiOS 32-bit?